# PHP and Mysql multiple updates - allowMultiQueries equivalent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have just started working with Laravel and I was wondering if there was an equivalent of the allowMultiQueries connection string parameter that I would use in java.

Is there way to do multiple updates in the same call or do they have to be done in succession?

```
DB::update('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename; CREATE TABLE tablename(...);');
```

instead of

```
DB::update('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename;'); 
DB::update('CREATE TABLE tablename(...);');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it fluently the Laravel way using [Schema Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/schema) like so

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

...

if (Schema::hasTable('tablename')) {
    Schema::drop('tablename');
}
Schema::create('tablename', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 64);
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->index('name');
});
```

But if you for some reason want to execute raw queries you can use [`unprepared()`](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Connection.html#_unprepared) method in [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)

```php
DB::unprepared('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename; CREATE TABLE tablename (id INT ...)');
```

but at least make sure you're using the proper syntax

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

instead of

```sql
DROP TABLE tablename IF EXISTS
```